# Does the function declaration mustn't appear within conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm new to Javascript, and I'm reading the Oreilly's Javascript the definitive guide. In the declaration statement section it says:

[image]

I made a simple test:

```
var a = 1;
while(a < 5){
    a++;
    function double(a){return a * 2 };
    console.log(double(a));
}
```

It seems the node.js doesn't give me any error and run as expect. Any comment on this?

Comment: Run it in strict mode, and you'll get your error. It's invalid syntax *(except if Mozilla's JS implementation where there's a similar syntax allowed)*, but has historically been permitted by implementations.

Answer (score -1):

That's not true. However you should keep in mind that they may not behave as you might expect.

For instance, this will work:

```
if( false) {
    function double(a) {return a*2;};
}
else {
    console.log(double(4));
}
```

Even though you might think the function is never defined due to being inside an `if` that is never reached, the function is in fact hoisted to the top of the current "block" (be it a containing function or the entire `<script>` tag or file) and are therefore accessible anywhere.

You *shouldn't* put `function` definitions inside an `if` block, but there's no reason why you can't.

Comment: there's plenty reasons you shouldn't - 1.  the spec says not to, 2. on some browsers, it doesn't work!

Comment: @Alnitak I specifically said you shouldn't. However according to the specifications on hoisting it's exactly the same as `var`.

Comment: It's not valid according to the spec, so what the specification describes about "hoisting" *(a term not used in the spec)* doesn't apply. The implementations may allow it, and may treat its hoisting the same, but it still isn't valid.